# Detect variation of numbers

Tags: java, kinect

I receive in my program continous position of the hand (with kinect), the output looks like this:

```
Hand position:838.64514
Hand position:840.4282
Hand position:852.3208
Hand position:866.03687
Hand position:893.8414
Hand position:921.6699
Hand position:945.2051
Hand position:972.0855
Hand position:1000.8606
Hand position:1025.4481
Hand position:1057.6517
Hand position:1084.9567
Hand position:1103.6124
Hand position:1129.9386
Hand position:1150.4238
Hand position:1165.6777
Hand position:1189.4777
Hand position:1209.6266
Hand position:1229.9663
Hand position:1243.3293
Hand position:1292.5873
Hand position:1277.4403
Hand position:1285.637
Hand position:1296.5696
Hand position:1281.771
Hand position:1348.9625
Hand position:1356.9446
Hand position:1357.5063
Hand position:1371.6934
Hand position:1357.644
Hand position:1363.991
Hand position:1346.6333
Hand position:1368.9194
Hand position:1319.148
Hand position:1309.4614
Hand position:1453.7458
Hand position:1293.8644
Hand position:1277.6212
Hand position:1266.6547
Hand position:1245.1154
Hand position:1233.5824
Hand position:1244.8787
Hand position:1227.302
Hand position:1211.7441
Hand position:1168.937
Hand position:1172.2562
Hand position:1141.3367
Hand position:1112.7675
Hand position:1079.6964
Hand position:1046.8102
Hand position:1002.8637
Hand position:966.8124
Hand position:1031.8394
Hand position:1041.4575
Hand position:969.2346
Hand position:857.4234
Hand position:845.1776
Hand position:828.65186
Hand position:829.81885
Hand position:835.6876
```

the number represent the z position of the hand. So z was approximately 800 and then it grew to approximately 1200 and then it come back to 800. All this represent one "Beat" or one "hit" with the hand. I want to detect this variation. I started coding something like this

```
if (position > oldPosition)
difference=difference+ position - oldPosition;

if (difference > 120)
println ( "One Hit");
difference=0;
oldPosition=position;
```

before I continue developing I wanted to be sure that's a good way to do that. Can you tell me if there is a better or more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: There's a lot of research going on in this area (websearch with terms like "Gesture Recognition" or similar), but I'd say that this is **not** very robust: Why 120? And... when the Hand is shaking a bit, between 799 and 800, (for 120 steps), then this will be recognized as a "hit" - this is not what you want. I'd probably start with somehow *smoothing* the input data ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing ), but this is just a first gut feeling.

Comment: Your example code will recognize the data you provided as two hits. Is this intended?

Comment: Your solution only seems to check for a maximum difference as the position increases. You need to then check for when it gets back close to 800 again. All this needs to happen over a time period, like half-second.

Comment: I check if (position > oldPosition) so when it gets beck close to 800 position will be < old position and it will not provide two hits or ? 120 is just for testing . 1300-800=500 so maybe 300 is better, i will just adjust it when i will test it

Comment: I did something pretty similar but I compared the current position with the 3 previous positions for more accuracy. It's more accurate to detect a real pattern and avoid a glitch

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the println, difference assignment and oldPosition reassignment lines are in that for loop (they probably are, just weird formatting on this site)

Also the second line should not be incremented. The difference will always be position - OldPosition.  No need to add it, just re-evaluate it each time position is updated.

Other than that, it should work. This will only give you a printout when the current hand position is different from the initial position by 120 z units.  I would however make sure you make sure you evaluate `if(Math.abs(difference) > 120)` to allow for negative difference as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the brackets, as they may have caused an error. Also if the direction matters you better not use the absolute value. You can use the following snippet in a function where you should initialize `difference` beforehand.

```
final int HIT_THRESHOLD = 120; // this might change depending on the 
                                   // camera(kinect) angle, distance and environment    
if (position != oldPosition) {
   difference += (position - oldPosition); // make sure both sides have the
                                                   // same type for the equation
}

if (difference > HIT_THRESHOLD) { // here is where you check for direction if necessary
                                  // you can do so by defining the threshold sign (-/+)

   println ( "One Hit");
   difference=0;
}

oldPosition=position;
```

Comment: Actually thats not correct for the second pair of brackets. Because in that case 'difference' will be equal to 0 everytime you check the position of hand and its value will never reach to threshold unless you receive position data at very low frames per second and you move your hand very very fast which will compromise the actual goal, "trying to catch a hit gesture". Brackets are not necessary for the first condition, yet its a good practice exactly because of the situation above.